# XGBoostError: [19:30:10] Cant identify what these type of errors relate to

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, xgboost

I've been trying to run XGBoost and when I attempt to plot the confusion matrix I get this error `XGBoostError: [19:30:10] c:\ci\xgboost-split_1638290375667\work\src\c_api\c_api_utils.h:161: Invalid missing value: null`

I get other similar errors `XGBoostError: [19:27:43]` and I am not sure what the numbers mean nor where to find the proper documentation to identify the problems my self.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: please add code and make your question reproducible so others can answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The numbers are the time the error happened, that is why is important to include full error messages.